# Changing a part of formula from relative reference to absolute reference

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am struggling with a cell reference problem. I have the following formula in cell B2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

Next, I use the autofill-function to make sure that all the cells until the last row have this formula. In column C I have static / hard values which are "leading". I need to sort the values in column C on largest to smallest. If I do this, the formula move across the spreadsheet.
For example, the new formula in cell B2 is:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A210,Sheet2!A:A,0))`

So, ideally I want to make sure that `MATCH(A2)` is transformed into `MATCH($A$2)` and the formula in row 3 is:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A3,Sheet2!A:A,0))`

However, I use the following VBA-module to create the formula:

```
Range("B2").Select
With Range("B2")
    .Formula = "=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
End With
```

This makes it impossible to use the locked `$A$2` from the start.

I am aware of the following function:

```
Application.ConvertFormula(Formula:=oRange.Formula, fromreferencestyle:=Application.ReferenceStyle, toabsolute:=xlAbsolute)
```

However, I am struggling with how to insert this function into my macro. If I use the following macro:

```
Range("M2").Select
With Range("M2")
    .Formula = "=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
End With                                                         
Range("M2:M" & LastRow).Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(Formula:="=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))", fromreferencestyle:=Application.ReferenceStyle, toabsolute:=xlAbsolute)
```

I get in each row the following formula:

```
 =INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C,MATCH($A$2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0))
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, your issue is to lock first argument of the MATCH function and simultaneously update it when filling down, am I right? If so, you could just fill down unlocked version of formula and then add dollar signs using Replace. See below:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range

Set rng = "define your range here"
For Each cl In rng
    cl.Formula = Replace(cl.Formula, "MATCH(A" & cl.Row, "MATCH($A$" & cl.Row)
Next cl
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning cells in your formula to variables. When you bring the variables into formulas use the [.address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213510(v=office.12).aspx) or [.addresslocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-addresslocal-property-excel) properties to freeze or keep relative references.

```
Dim MyMatch as range
Set MyMatch = range("a2")

range("m2").formula = “INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(” & MyMatch.Address & “,Sheet2!A:A,0))”
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank you both for your answer. 
Both your methods worked, however due to large number of rows, the macro took a long time to run.
In the end, I shortened this and achieved my desired result with the following macro:

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = True
Cells.Select
Selection.Replace What:="Sheet1!B", Replacement:="Sheet1!$B", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = False
```

Nevertheless, thank you for your time.